# Dropping Mongo collection not clearing disk space

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with 750,000 documents, it's taking around 7Gb on the disk.

I've dropped the collection, but the files (`test.0`...`test.11`) are still on the disk.

- If I delete them, then I loose all the collections, not just the one I dropped
- Shouldn't Mongo be deleting them?

Just noticed that the database stats have an error.

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Collection [test.loadTest-2016-02-06 15:05:34Z] not found."
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have dropped a collection, but not the database containing it. Dropping the collection does not compact the data files, nor does deleting a document. If you really want to compact the database, either drop it entirely and reimport it, or compact it using `repairDatabase` (see the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#how-do-i-reclaim-disk-space)). Beware though, you cannot compact the database online I think if you just have one node.

If you have a replica set, adding new nodes and removing the old ones is the safest way of compacting the database online. I do that from time to time and it's easy.

Comment: Are you saying that dropping a collection just removes the reference to it, it doesn't destroy it?

Comment: Yes, that's how MongoDB works when deleting things (check the [Empty records](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#empty-records) paragraph in the docs).

Comment: Note: This answer only applies to the MMAPv1 storage engine (which is being used in the original question). As a reference for those coming across this discussion using modern versions of MongoDB (3.2+), the default storage engine is now WiredTiger. WiredTiger has different behaviour: dropping a collection or index will remove the associated files and free up disk space, and the [`compact` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/) should be used to try to free space in existing data files (if possible) during a maintenance window.

Comment: Just want to clarify: in WiredTiger, dropping a collection DOES free disk space.  No `compact` or any other maintenance command is needed.  Just drop the collection, and the disk space should be automatically freed.