# MongoDb atlas giving "MongoError: Error determining if update will go over space quota: Error dialing backend: no reachable servers"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am using MongoDB Altas M0 instance. For 6 months it was working fine.

Now I am getting error about space quota. I checked I am nowhere close to the mentioned quota. I am still getting this error.

Here is the full stacktrace:-

```
MongoError: Error determining if update will go over space quota: Error dialing backend: no reachable servers
at Function.MongoError.create (/home/ubuntu/Cricket2017Server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
at /home/ubuntu/Cricket2017Server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:483:72
at authenticateStragglers (/home/ubuntu/Cricket2017Server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:429:16)
at Connection.messageHandler (/home/ubuntu/Cricket2017Server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:463:5)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Cricket2017Server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:319:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:547:20)

Details:  MongoError: Error determining if update will go over space quota: Error dialing backend: no reachable servers
```

[image]

Any suggestion would be great help.

Comment: It looks the problems is most likely because you have the "sandbox" version and you used up the available space. You need to upgrade

Comment: As shown in the snapshot, I am nowhere near the max limit which is 512 MB. This should not be the issue

Comment: Did you tried to contact with the Atlas support? The "problem" is from the Atlas side.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the "problem" is related with the processes in the third-party service

Answer (score 2):

What likely has happened is that, over the course of several months, you have deleted documents or dropped collections. However, the database does not compact.

So 3.1 MB as in your image is the "logical size". The actual size, due to six months of operations without compacting, is 512 MB.

You can drop the entire database and rewrite it from local copy, or you can repairDatabase. See this other [StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242743/dropping-mongo-collection-not-clearing-disk-space) for more information.